# Return the highest value from model to view

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I want to know how to compare these 2 outputs http://prntscr.com/bx7ay9 and return the highest `value` in the `array` ?

**MY MODEL CODES**

```
$this->db->select('additional');
$this->db->from('order_detail');
$this->db->where('order_id',$id);
$query = $this->db->get();
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   $return[] = $row->additional;
}
return $return;
```

Comment: For such a small output example, it is probably better to just write the outputs directly here instead of sending a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `select_max` in query to get highest value and use `row()` to fetch single row without using `foreach loop` as

```
$this->db->select_max('additional AS max_value');
$this->db->from('order_detail');
$this->db->where('order_id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get();
$ret = $query->row();
return $ret->max_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the max number then use [select_max()](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=select#CI_DB_query_builder::select_max),

```
$this->db->select_max('additional');
$this->db->from('order_detail');
$this->db->where('order_id',$id);
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows()){// check if data is not empty
   return $query->row()->additional;
}
return false;// you can return false here
```

**And** if you want to get the result array for another use then, you can use [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) with `$this->db->select('additional');` with your code to get the max number in array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('additional');
    $this->db->from('order_detail');
    $this->db->where('order_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
       $return[] = max($row->additional);

    }
    return $return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just used `select_max` of Codeigniter Query Bulder Class.

Model,

```
public function get_max ($id){

    $this->db->select_max('additional');
    $this->db->where('order_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('order_detail');

    return $query->row();
}
```

In Controller,

```
$max = $this->Model->get_max($id);
echo $max['additional']; // Display and see the value.
```